# Using PHPUnit to test a Laravel package inside a host application with Github actions?

Tags: laravel, github-actions

## Summary

I have a package that needs to be wrapped by a real laravel app to be tested properly. Unfortunately I cant use the orchestra testbench. However I have setup a Github action for this. But, when running the final step `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit path/to/package` im experiencing the following issues:

- PHPUnit can't resolve certain classes
- It thinks PHPUnit `setUp()` is public in my parent class though it is protected.
- I suspect some issue with caching or delay after push (but I have tested wiping all cache,
  autoload and config)

### Example error

```
Run vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit packages/Ajthinking/PHPFileManipulator/tests
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPFileManipulator\Tests\FileTestCase' not found in /home/runner/work/php-file-manipulator/php-file-manipulator/host/packages/Ajthinking/PHPFileManipulator/tests/Unit/APIDelegationTest.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 /home/runner/work/php-file-manipulator/php-file-manipulator/host/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php(59): include_once()
#1 /home/runner/work/php-file-manipulator/php-file-manipulator/host/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php(47):
```

Reviewing my master branch, the requested file `FileTestCase` *is* there.

#### The full action script:

```
name: Laravel-wrapped-package-test

on: [push]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Install host app
      run: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel host

    - name: Install package (this repo)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        path: host/packages/Ajthinking/PHPFileManipulator

    - name: Add this package to composer.json repositories
      uses: ajthinking/merge-json-files@v1.0.20
      with:
        repo_relative_path: 'host/packages/Ajthinking/PHPFileManipulator'

    - name: Require this package
      working-directory: ./host
      run: composer require ajthinking/php-file-manipulator @dev

    - name: Publish things
      working-directory: ./host
      run: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="PHPFileManipulator\ServiceProvider"       

    - name: Run tests
      working-directory: ./host      
      run: vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit packages/Ajthinking/PHPFileManipulator/tests
```

### TestCase

Below is my base test case. But the setUp method is never called. (Previously it was called TestCase as the default laravel provides - it was renamed while debugging)

```
<?php

namespace PHPFileManipulator\Tests; 

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class FileTestCase extends BaseTestCase  
{
    protected function setUp() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        dd("it will never reach this dd call on github actions!");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php

namespace PHPFileManipulator\Tests\Unit;

use PHPFileManipulator\Tests\FileTestCase;

class StupidTest extends FileTestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function it_can_run_tests()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }    
}
```

### versions

Im using PHP 7.4.2 and PHPUnit 8.5.2 (same as github actions ubuntu-latest) Mimicing the action script on my own machine works fine.
I have reviewed CASE on github/local found no differences.

Any ideas, what I am missing?

Comment: Do you have this file in your app? If not, put it and see if it helps.
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/tests/TestCase.php

Also, see if you have something like this in your composer.json -
`"autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },`

Comment: Can you show us example test class?

Comment: @QumberRizvi, I have added my base test case to the question. (TestCase was renamed when debugging). Im autoloading "tests/" into namespace "Tests\\" in composer.json

Comment: @WahyuKristianto, added sample test

Comment: @Anders I tried it, but it didn't work. However, when writing packages, your package will not typically have access to all of Laravel's testing helpers. If you would like to be able to write your package tests as if they existed inside a typical Laravel application, you may use the Orchestral Testbench package.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use the orchestra testbench

Comment: If Laravel is a dependency for your package it should be stated in its `composer.json` file. Wouldn't be easier to just run `composer install` from your CI script to install all the necessary dependencies and run `vendor/bin/phpunit` from there (package root) instead of creating a fresh laravel project, installing your package and running the tests from a subfolder?

Comment: @mdexp, I need to mimic being inside a Laravel application on disk, not only use it as a dependency

Comment: @Anders why can't you use orchestra testbench?

Comment: @DiogoGomes I need to mimic being inside a Laravel application on disk, not only use it as a dependency. I need fysical default files to be present, for instance app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php etc. Possibly I could mock that, but I would prefer the real thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I failed updating the host app `composer.json` repositories section. That meant requiring the package with `@dev` flag (taking latest commit) had no effect 
 - instead an outdated package version was pulled from packagagist.

#### Fixed github workflow:

```
name: tests

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Install host app
      run: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel host

    - name: Checkout the package
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        path: host/packages/Ajthinking/PHPFileManipulator

    - name: Add composer.json repository
      working-directory: ./host      
      run: composer config repositories.php-file-manipulator path "/home/runner/work/php-file-manipulator/php-file-manipulator/host/packages/Ajthinking/PHPFileManipulator"

    - name: Require the package
      working-directory: ./host
      run: composer require ajthinking/php-file-manipulator @dev

    - name: Publish things
      working-directory: ./host
      run: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="PHPFileManipulator\ServiceProvider"

    - name: Run tests
      working-directory: ./host      
      run: vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit packages/Ajthinking/PHPFileManipulator/tests
```